# Formatting an external ssd

Tags: synchronization

2 questions about bitcoin core

i formatted the ssd and used exfat, i'm using windows, should be ok, right??  or should i cancel my block download remove Core reformat the drive to NFTS and start again

second question i put the default directory to the E: drive, the ssd, but the installer still created a folder called Bitcoin in my c:/ program files

i don't suppose it's a big deal i just want the node to work and not be pruned, so i bought a 2 tb samsung T7

Comment: Well, I think the folder on C drive was from the old installation I removed 4 days ago, so I just shift-del, didn't seem to affect the block download, so there'